# How to stop PublishPipelineArtifact ignoring .git directory

Tags: azure-devops

I have been developing an Azure Devops CICD pipeline for java applications built with maven. This was working a few months ago when I had to park it. Now it fails because the .git directory isn't included when I publish the artifacts at the end of the first stage.

I can see this in the output if I enable system diagnostics

```
2021-08-24T21:12:12.9417903Z Information, Processing .artifactignore file surfaced 30 files. Total files under source directory: 474
2021-08-24T21:12:12.9418814Z Verbose, Ignoring the following files/folders:
2021-08-24T21:12:12.9419773Z Verbose, /home/vsts/work/1/s/.git/FETCH_HEAD
...
```

This is the task

```yaml
# copy downloaded git repository including build in target directory , for use in next stage
      - publish:
        artifact: repository
```

I don't have an .artifactignore file.

Is there anyway to stop this happening?

Comment: I have a workaround, renaming .git to git before publishing and reverting the name in the next stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to stop PublishPipelineArtifact ignoring .git directory

Accordig to the document [Use the .artifactignore file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops)：

**Ignored by default**:

> To reduce the chances of publishing the .git folder, we automatically
> ignore this path. You can re-include it by adding the following line
> to your .artifactignore file:
>
> ```
> !.git
> ```

So,  you could try to add the `.artifactignore` file with content `!.git` into the root of the repository.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked and oops it reminded me that I had the same solution in a different project about 6 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-artifacts)

```
steps:
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
  artifact: WebApp
```

> The path of the file or folder to publish is required. It can be an absolute or a relative path to $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory).

Please add path to your publish step.

Comment: Thanks but made no difference, .git is still ignored. I have a workaround, renaming .git to git before publishing and reverting the name in the next stage.